# angular 4 (or greater versions) circuit breaker implementation

Tags: angular

if we do any external service call from Angular applications (version >= 4) then,

1. How to recognize transient failures?
2. How to handle it like the way we
   do with circuit breaker implementation in Spring Boot or other
   applications?

In production people use retry.

```
return this._http.get(url, {headers: headers, params: params}).retry(2).catch(error => {
      return Observable.throw(error.message || error);
});
```

If server is busy processing request and because of retry even if a single call is made further then it will add to the servers recovery time. Is not it?